# Java 8 - Permanent Generation Support - Alernative

Tags: java, jvm, java-8

Support to PermGen Pool has now been removed in Java 8. 
What is the alternative for PermGen Pool in Java 8. How & where java 8(JVM) is storing per-class structure & internal string.

Does it also mean that we will not get the "java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space" error

Comment: Upvoting because I had no idea Java 8 was released yet.

Comment: http://www.infoq.com/news/2013/03/java-8-permgen-metaspace

Comment: http://java.dzone.com/articles/java-8-permgen-metaspace

Answer (score 1):

It will use Metaspace which is PermGen successor. More info [here](http://java.dzone.com/articles/java-8-permgen-metaspace).

To answer your question

> A new flag is available (MaxMetaspaceSize), allowing you to limit the amount of native memory used for class metadata. If you don’t specify this flag, the Metaspace will dynamically re-size depending of the application demand at runtime.

So yes due to dynamic re-sizing the `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space` will not occur till native memory is exhausted but still you need to take care of class and classloader memory leaks.